# Laravel 5 BETWEEN query syntax

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have this problem:

I post value from datapicker to Controller and get correct value. Now, I need to write query, to get value from DB where posted value match:

This query is ok in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE date( created_at ) = '2015-07-24'
```

Now, I try something like this to get value from DB, but no succes:

```
$result = Orders::select('SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE date( created_at ) = "2015-07-24" ');
```

No errors,but get all data,and need to be one result.

And after that,to send result to view :

```
return view('index',compact('result'));
```

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

As your created_at is time-stamp so, we need to compare it with another time-stamp.

while strtotime convert any date into time-stamp.

Use

```
$result = Orders::where('created_at' ,'=' ,strtotime('2015-07-24'))->get();
```

Comment: Yeah,I try this too:) But, look at this , I need to use mysql DATE function,to get only date form time stam date( created_at ), how can I use that i your query ?

Comment: Your created_at column is time stamp??

Comment: Yeah... And I need just to check dates to match

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution :

```
$result =Orders::whereBetween('created_at', array( '2015-07-24 00:00:00' , '2015-07-24 23:59:59'))->get();
```